# SpringBoot not calling @PreUpdate on http PATCH

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot

I have an entity annotated with `EntityListener` and a subsequent listener class.
This entity does not have a custom controller, meaning that SpringBoot automatically creates the controller with the endpoints.

Using debug mode, when doing a HTTP **`PUT`** operation, I can see that my **`@PreUpdate`** method is being called and correctly executed.

When I call the HTTP **`PATCH`** operation, it does not pause execution at my breakpoint inside the **`@PreUpdate`** method. (This is not an issue with my debugger)

Am I missing something?

Comment: Are you getting a `Method Not Allowed` response in your client side?

Comment: No, PATCH works as expected, except it does not call my @PrePersist method.

Comment: There's an open bug - from some years ago. https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAREST-466

Comment: "@PreUpdate methods ARE called on PATCH when the entity is actual modified (not called if you PATCH the same payload twice)." I was testing with the same payload, hence not doing the preupdate method. You helped me a lot @Samiron, thanks. Feel free to include this 'detail' in an answer and I'll accept it!